# Adding elements to BeautifulSoup's find_all list as a string

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am testing a webscraping concept with BeautifulSoup's findall() function. I'm trying to get the contents of the p tags that have the class='first' inside of div class='dinner'.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

html_doc="""
<html>
<head>
<title>The practice html document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class='dinner'>
<p class='first'>I like pizza</p>
<p class='second'>I really like pizza</p>
<p class='first'>pizza is good</p> 
</div>
<div class='breakfast'>
<p class='first'>pancake</p>
</div>
<div class='lunch'>
<p> This is a paragraph</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
div_stuff=soup.find("div", attrs={'class':'dinner'})
print div_stuff
print '\n'
#This prints the paragraphs only in the div with the class dinner
div_paragraphs=unicode(div_stuff.find_all('p', attrs={'class':'first'}))
print div_paragraphs
```

The findall function puts the paragraphs it finds as an element in a list. This is the output of the code:

```
<div class="dinner">
<p class="first">I like pizza</p>
<p class="second">I really like pizza</p>
<p class="first">pizza is good</p>
</div>

[<p class="first">I like pizza</p>, <p class="first">pizza is good</p>]
```

The goal is to get just the content of the paragraphs as strings in the list. Like this:

```
[I like pizza,pizza is good]
```

I could make some code that would go through each element and replace them after it has found all instances, but I wanted to see if there is a way to make them strings before findall stores each one into the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.findall()` will return matches; you are looking for the elements, not for the contained text (which would be a very different search).

You can easily extract the text in a list comprehension:

```
[elem.get_text() for elem in soup.select('div.dinner p.first')]
```

I used a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) here to match the `p` tags in context of their `div` parents.

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html_doc="""
... <html>
... <head>
... <title>The practice html document</title>
... </head>
... <body>
... <div class='dinner'>
... <p class='first'>I like pizza</p>
... <p class='second'>I really like pizza</p>
... <p class='first'>pizza is good</p> 
... </div>
... <div class='breakfast'>
... <p class='first'>pancake</p>
... </div>
... <div class='lunch'>
... <p> This is a paragraph</p>
... </div>
... </body>
... </html>
... """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
>>> [elem.get_text() for elem in soup.select('div.dinner p.first')]
[u'I like pizza', u'pizza is good']
```